# Current Month Filter in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Trying to filter by current Month in a table.  I know I can use the "m" but not sure what to replace it with.

Or this there an easier way to write it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: To make an expression, either put an `=` before the expression, or use the builder... Otherwise SSRS assumes this is a value

Comment: It tried that too..  still get the same erorr.  I added screen shots

Comment: No... To define an expression in the Value, use `=`, not `>=`, just `=`. Use `>=` in the operator

Comment: ok i dont get an error in the syntx but running the report give me a 'm' is not declared.  i added the screnn shot above

Answer (score 0):

The expression for the filter value should be:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, CDate("1/1/1900"), Today), CDate("1/1/1900"))
```

Comment: Steve, I added that expression (see picture added)  while i dont get an error. I dont get any lines as well report is blank

Comment: @MarqueePhillip Well, are any of the fulfillment dates actually at midnight on the first day of the month? If not, you need to convert those as well so they match each other.

Comment: I hard coded dates in the data set...  maybe i just create a another dataset with a date filter there.  but i cant seem to find the right one for firebrid ()current month)

Comment: @MarqueePhillip You should use the `Between` operator and give it the first and last day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, CDate("1/1/1900"), Today) + 1, CDate("1/1/1900"))
```

Comment: Not surewhy this is giving me a hard time.  Still no data but we have over 200 lines that should be showing up.  its a firebrid odbc connection would that matter ?

Comment: I hard coded dates in the data set...  maybe i just create a another dataset with a date filter there.  but i cant seem to find the right one for firebrid (current month)